# Conflict in repo name and module name

Tags: go

I created the `github.com` project `qjson/qjson-go` that contains the package name `qjson` that you can see [here](https://github.com/qjson/qjson-go). I named the github project this way because `github.com/qjson/` contains other projects for different languages (e.g. `qjson-c`).

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to import the project as `github.com/qjson/qjson-go`:

```
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/qjson/qjson-go
go: downloading github.com/qjson/qjson-go v0.0.0-20210128102242-170c47e2db46
github.com/xxx/xxx imports
    github.com/qjson/qjson-go: module github.com/qjson/qjson-go@latest found (v0.0.0-20210128102242-170c47e2db46), but does not contain package github.com/qjson/qjson-go
```

I’m apparently doing it wrong. I understand that due to the import statement we are then expected to use `gjson-go` as package identifier.

What must I do so that the git project can be named `qjson-go` and the package `qjson` ?

I assume that one solution is to create a sub-directory named `qjson` inside `qjson-go` and move all package files in it. The user would then `import "github.com/qson/qson-go/qjson"`. Is that correct ? Is there another solution avoiding the stutter ?

Comment: It should work as you initially described. There are other known modules that use the same naming scheme like https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go.

Comment: Just a guess: `qjson-go` is not a valid identifier in Go, as the `-` is an operator. You'll have to rename the module in the import statement.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that is not the explanation since the module opentracing-go has also a - in the name and the module name.

Comment: That's right, @chmike, just checked that as well. I wonder what the mechanism is that turns `opentracing-go` into `opentracing` though.

Comment: One difference between the packages is that your's has its actual code in the `qjson` subdirectory, while opentracing-go starts in the repository root. Have you tried `import "github.com/qson/qson-go/qjson"`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You found it. That’s a stupid mistake. If you provide an answer, I’ll validate it. Thank you very much. I did that because I had the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program works as expected:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/qjson/qjson-go/qjson"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println(qjson.ErrDivisionByZero)
}
```

The issue is that you are using this file structure:

```
qjson/engine.go
qjson/errors.go
```

When you should just be putting them at the top level, like this:

```
engine.go
errors.go
```

So you can either fix the directory, and tag a new version, or just leave the
files as is, and change your imports to match what I have above.